# Checking if an array contains a string

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I'm trying to evaluate if an entered string partially matches any item in an array. When I use the following method in playgrounds it seems to work properly. However, when I use the exact same method in Xcode 9.0 beta 6 (9M214v) it doesn't return the correct answer.

```
func isValid(_ item: String)  -> Bool {
    let whitelist = ["https://apple.com","https://facebook.com","https://stackoverflow.com"]

    return whitelist.contains(where: {$0 <= item ? true : false  })
}
```

There's also anomalies like when I passed in "https://twitter.com" it'll return true. Am I nuts? And while I'm here, anyone have a different approach to solve this problem?

Comment: `$0 <= item` what does that mean ?

Comment: As @MikeAlter commented, what's the logic of comparing like `$0 <= item`?

Comment: You state it works in playgrounds. Which version? Do you actually mean this works in Swift 3 but not Swift 4? Please clarify.

Comment: @rmaddy swift 4 playgrounds. When I said it worked, my expectations and understanding of what happening in my playground was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> theres also anomalies like when I passed in "https://twitter.com"
>   it'll return true.

Whether the version of Swift is 3 or 4, based on your code snippet you should get the *same* `true` result! Why?

because the logic of [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) of doing the comparison is related to the logic of the *equality* of the given elements, i,e you cannot use `contains` with array of non-equatable elements. To make it more clear:

```
"https://apple.com" <= "https://twitter.com"
"https://facebook.com" <= "https://twitter.com"
"https://stackoverflow.com" <= "https://twitter.com"
```

the result would be `true` for *all* statements ('t' character is greater than 'a', 'f' and 's').

Thus:

```
"https://zwebsite" <= "https://twitter.com"
```

would returns `false` ('t' is less than 'z').

However, to get the expected result, you could implement your function like this:

```
func isValid(_ item: String)  -> Bool {

    let whitelist = ["https://apple.com","https://facebook.com","https://stackoverflow.com"]

    return whitelist.contains { $0 == item }
}
```

Or for even a shorter `contains`:

```
return whitelist.contains(item)
```

Which leads to let

```
isValid("https://twitter.com")
```

to returns `false`.

Comment: It should check the next character in the string, like the case of "https://", until reaching the last element (character), if all matched then it will be an equality.

Comment: So what's happening is that its evaluating whether each character is < = the character in the same position. I was under the impression that it was evaluating each item as a one string rather than an array of characters. 

What I'm trying to do is see if the scheme & host of particular URL matches one in the array. using only `contains` won't account for the rest of the URL and will return `false` even it the first part is in the array.

Comment: Well, that would be completely another case :) you should work with `URL` and `URLComponenets` to achieve it, I could update my answer, but it will be unrelated to the title of your question...

Answer (score 0):

Just return the following, which will return `true` or `false`:

```
return whitelist.contains(item)
```